# Normalization Excercise Clarification

Tags: database-design, normalization

Have a bit of confusion regarding a normalization from 1NF to BCNF.  The teacher gave us this excercise to illustrate a normalisation all the way up to BCNF.  I think I have found a problem with the given solution and would like to clear this up.

The way I have solved it up to **3NF** is as follows:
[image: 1NF]

My understanding is that there are **TWO** partial dependencies here

The Primary key is made up of (**SID, InstructorID**)

1. The **Subject** is dependent only on the the **InstructorID** and not on the entire primary key
2. The **Name** is dependent only on the **SID** only and not on the entire primary key

[image: 2NF]

Finally, **3NF** where the transitive dependency has now been removed and refactored into it's own table.
No **BCNF** violations here!!!
[image: 3NF]

**QUESTION:**

Is my solution correct?

have I correctly performed the **2NF** step?

Comment: You say *"The teachers solution differed in that he left the Grade in the table at the 2NF step and therefore had to remove it at the BCNF normalization level."*
Did you mean *"The teachers solution differed in that he left the Grade in the table at the **3NF** step and therefore had to remove it at the BCNF normalization level."*

Comment: Thanks for the comment! that is quite confusing isn't it! I have changed it to better reflect my meaning (I hope) - That he did not identify the Subject -> Grade dependency as a partial dependency

Comment: Yes, but you say that he left it at the 2NF step. I guess you mean the 2NF->3NF step.

Comment: But Subject->Grade dependency? I don't see that either in yours. Do you mean Gradepoint->Grade dependency?

Comment: I might remove the part about the teachers answer because it is very confusing looking back at it.  I mean at the 1NF -> 2NF step but I see now that its pretty hard to understand!! Thanks!

Comment: Your solution looks correct, yes, give or take a few misconceptions, e.g. about primary key.

Comment: Primary key is a no go? curious about your thoughts on that!

Comment: But we can't possibly comment on the "mistake on the given solution" without knowing what that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105159/discussion-between-afm-horizon-and-ypercube).

Comment: There is no concept or primary key in normalization. There are candidate keys and there can be more than one, as in your case.  (SID, InstructorID) is only one of the candidate keys. You missed some dependencies, so you missed some candidate keys as a consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Subject exists only as an attribute of instructor.
- A grade is associated with an instructor-student pair, rather than a 'class'.

This means that:

- A student would not be able to take more than one class with an instructor.
- Information regarding the subject itself (for example its full name) would not be storable, which seems like a likely request. I'm suggesting to preemptively create a 'Subject' table even though it currently only has one column.
- If an instructor changed their subject, that would implicitly change the subject for all past grades given by that instructor.

Answer (score 1):

So The question has been answered in great detail in chat by ypercubetm https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9

The short anwer is **yes** the solution above is one possible correct solution

Many thanks to ypercubetm for taking the time breaking it down for me!